# Windows 7 - "Alt-tab" gadget or application to show miniatures of all open apps in a window

Tags: windows-7, window, alt-tab, desktop-gadget

I'm looking for some kind of persistent "alt-tab" window, which woul allow to see miniatures of active windows, as the Alt+Tab shortcut does (but can't be always shown AFAIK).

Some ideas or cool apps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Tiles](http://www.stardock.com/products/tiles/index.asp) from StarDock. (free version has the requested feature)

With Tiles you can quickly view and manage your running applications by simply looking to the edge of your screen.

[image: Screenshot of Tiles]

Answer (score 1):

Use [VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html) which pimps up <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. It is **free** and work for Vista and Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: I read from the site, but I did not see if it was capable of displaying what I want, @Lamb's answer is closer to what I want, but I would have to pay to use it.

Comment: @Lamb's answer leads to exactly what I wanted. Thanks & +1 for the help.